# c# how to place cursor at postion in richtextbox

Tags: c#, copy, richtextbox, paste

I have a richtextbox in WinForms and have created a copy and paste function and I can copy and paste at my cursor. HOWEVER, once have pasted my cursor moves to the start of the richtextbox. how do I get it to either stay at the position or move to the end of the pasted section?

I have tried

```
Point p = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
rtbNotePad.PointToClient(p); //but does not work.

private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtbNotePad.Copy();
}

private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pasteText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text).ToString();
    Point p = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);

    if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
    {
        rtbNotePad.Text = rtbNotePad.Text.Insert(rtbNotePad.SelectionStart, Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text).ToString());
        rtbNotePad.PointToClient(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't reassign the Text property, that forces RTB to move the cursor back because the text completely changed.  Instead use rtbNotePad.SelectedText = ClipBoard.GetText();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `SelectionStart` property to control the cursor position in `ReachtextBox`.

```
    private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pasteText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text).ToString();

        if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
        {
            var start = rtbNotePad.SelectionStart; // use this if you want to keep cursor where it was
            //start += pasteText.Length;    // use this if want to move cursor to the end of pasted text
            rtbNotePad.Text = rtbNotePad.Text.Insert(rtbNotePad.SelectionStart, Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text).ToString());

            rtbNotePad.SelectionStart = start;
           // rtbNotePad.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are directly changing the Text which will lose all previous formatting. Use hans' method!

Comment: @TaW You are right, but that's not me. That's what OP does. The question was about handling the cursor position after the paste and my answer is the exact solution of the problem.

Comment: What is "hans' method?  did I mention I am new to building C#?  so I want to make sure I am not only using the right method, but the best method. and I may not know the exact way to ask the question.